# Mongo DB aggregate query match and project together with and operator not working

Tags: mongodb

I have this document in mongo db:

```
 {
        "_id" : 8,
        "semester" : 3,
        "grades" : [ 
            {
                "grade" : 92,
                "mean" : 88,
                "std" : 8,
                "scores" : [ 
                    {
                        "fistSem" : 100,
                        "secondSem" : 60
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "grade" : 78,
                "mean" : 90,
                "std" : 5,
                "scores" : [ 
                    {
                        "fistSem" : 100,
                        "secondSem" : 60
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "grade" : 88,
                "mean" : 85,
                "std" : 3,
                "scores" : [ 
                    {
                        "fistSem" : 72,
                        "secondSem" : 60
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

This Query

```
db.getCollection('grades').aggregate({"$project":{"grades.std":1,"grades.grade":1}},{"$match":{"$and":[{"grades.grade":92},{"grades.std":8}]}});
```

gives me following output:

```
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "grade" : 92,
            "std" : 8
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : 78,
            "std" : 5
        }, 
        {
            "grade" : 88,
            "std" : 3
        }
    ] }
```

I am expecting:

```
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "grade" : 92,
            "std" : 8
        } ] }
```

Not sure why we are getting even non-match array elements. We are using mongo db 3.2

Comment: `$match` filters documents (not array elements) to pass to the next step in the pipeline. Have you tried `$unwind` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below query:

```
db.getCollection('grades').find({"grades.grade":92"grades.std":8},{"grades.$":1});
```

**UPDATE:**

```
db.getCollection('grades').aggregate([
{$match:{_id:8}},
{$unwind:"$grades"},
{$match:{"grades.grade":92,"grades.std":8}},
{$project:{"_id":"$_id",grades:{grade:"$grades.grade", std:"$grades.std"}}}
]);
```

Comment: This filters data property but I want to get only selected fields in the output. This query returns all fields.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
db.getCollection('grades').find({"grades.grade":92, "grades.std":8},{"grades.$":1})
```

output

```
{
    "_id" : 8,
    "grades" : [ 
        {
            "grade" : 92,
            "mean" : 88,
            "std" : 8,
            "scores" : [ 
                {
                    "fistSem" : 100,
                    "secondSem" : 60
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```